# How to get the boot time and up time for windows phone 8 using C#

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to get the boot time and uptime for windows phone 8 using C# and XAML. Also kindly advice if there are some different methods of doing it in windows phone 8 and windows phone 7.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: What would XAML have to do with that?

Comment: I was just mentioning the language combination I am using... It will not be used...

Answer (score 2):

```
System.Environment.TickCount
```

returns the number of milliseconds since boot up.

Comment: System.Environment.TickCount is not available in windows phone 8 sdk.

Comment: It is definitely available for Windows Phone 8, I am using it in my current app. It's also available in WinRT. But keep in mind it is an int so at about 25 days it will reach the int.Max value and become a negative number.

Answer (score 0):

These values are not available in Windows Phone 7/8, AFAIK.